# Is it possible to get larger image size for company logos via the Linkedin API?

Tags: image, api, linkedin-api

See the one that comes back from

`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/id=1337:(id,name,logo-url)`

it's quite small! https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/p/6/005/056/054/057ffb7.png

Would be great if could get a larger version

(note, the apigee console [here](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin?req=%7B%22resource%22:%22getcompanybyid%22,%22params%22:%7B%22query%22:%7B%7D,%22template%22:%7B%22id%22:%221337:(id,name,logo-url)%22%7D,%22headers%22:%7B%7D,%22body%22:%7B%22attachmentFormat%22:%22mime%22,%22attachmentContentDisposition%22:%22form-data%22%7D%7D,%22verb%22:%22get%22%7D) may be helpful)

Answer (score 1):

The information you're looking for is in the member profile field documentation on LinkedIn's developer website:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/basic-profile

> picture-urls::(original)
>
> A URL to the member's original unformatted profile picture.  This
> image is usually larger than the picture-url value above.

Comment: This is only for basic-profile and not for a company.